# How to add a column of a constant value from a query to another query result?

Tags: mysql

Basically, I have two tables. From table A, I want to calculate the total number of rows from it. I can use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A` as the first query to get it. From other table B, I want to select all things(columns) from it. I can use `SELECT * FROM B` as the second query. My question is how to use a single query to add the result from the first query as a column to the second query result. In other words, I want to have an extra column with the value of total number of rows from Table A to all things from Table B, by using a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CROSS JOIN it:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM A) a
  CROSS JOIN
  B
```

Join makes the resultset wider. Union makes the resultset taller. Any time you want to grow the number of columns you have to join, but if you haven't got anything to join *ON* you can use a CROSS JOIN as it doesn't require any ON predicates

You could alternatively use an INNER JOIN with a predicate that is always true, an old style join syntax without any associated WHERE, or you can put a select that returns a single value as a subquery in the select list area without any co-ordinating predicates. Most DBA would probably assert that none of these are preferable to the CROSS JOIN syntax because CROSS JOIN is an explicit statement of your intent, whereas the others might just look like you forgot something

Comment: Thanks Caius! Your answer is very helpful!